# Twilio Answering Machine Detection - specific use case for initial audio play without waiting AMD result

Tags: twilio

Our use case is simple - we're using Twilio to make appointment reminder phone calls, but we want to only start leaving the message in the case of an answering machine/voicemail after the final "beep".  Our current method is to loop through the message twice to account for voicemail greetings of different length cutting of the first loop of the reminder message play.
    We are experimenting with Twilio AMD - but we're having some difficulty and not sure if it's flexible enough to meet our use case needs.  Specifically, we'd like to continue our very initial prompt that plays to check if it's a human picking up the call - the initial prompt is "This is a reminder from your doctor's office, please press any key to continue" - and if we confirm it's a human we start playing the reminder message immediately.  If it's not a human picking up (e.g. no keypad entry) only in that case are we looking for the Twilio AMD to provide the end of message/beep detection to know the right time (e.g. after the voicemail greeting is done and makes the "beep") to start playing our reminder greeting.  We are correctly enabling AMD currently - but the problem is that if we pickup the call but don't say anything - even our initial prompt that we want to be played immediately without any AMD result won't play until the AMD times out (which is set at the default of 30 sec).  The Twilio documentation was not entirely clear on if there's an option to play/TTS content even before waiting for the AMD detection and then only use the end message/beep detection result to handle the machine picking up case - or if having AMD enabled overrides everything and won't let you run any code until it returns a value.  Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio AMD does not allow you to do anything with the call before the detection is complete.

Currently the AMD is also being revamped as it was not performing as well as we'd like. Look out for a new version of AMD later in the year.